# Sending Objects between activities implementing parcelable

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, android-activity

I need to send an object from an activity to another; I read that one way is to implement parcelable interface into my object.
I arranged some code but I think I'm messing up.
Here is part of my code.
The object I want to send:

```
public class Profilo implements Parcelable {

String nome;
String cognome;
....

public Profilo(String nome,String cognome,String dataNascita,String luogoNascita,String problematica,String dettagli)
{
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cognome = cognome;    
....
}


public Profilo(Parcel parcel) {
    this.nome = parcel.readString();
    this.cognome = parcel.readString();
 }

.... 

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(nome);
    dest.writeString(cognome);

}

public final static Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    @Override
    public Profilo createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Profilo(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Profilo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Profilo[size];
    }  
};

}
```

Then the activity that sends the object (an ArrayList of Profilo objects):

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

public ArrayList<Profilo>profili = new ArrayList<Profilo>(10);

....
       final Button Login = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button2);
   Login.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           Intent intent = new Intent(cont, LoginChooser.class);
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           bundle.putParcelable("profilo", (Parcelable) profili);
           intent.putExtras(bundle);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
    });
```

Then the activity that receive the object:

```
public class LoginChooser extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_chooser);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    ArrayList ListaProfili = (ArrayList)bundle.getParcelable("punto");
    Profilo listaProfili[] = (Profilo[]) ListaProfili.toArray();
    String nomeProfilo[] = new String[10];
    int index = 0;
    for(Profilo elem : listaProfili) {
        if(elem!= null) {
            nomeProfilo[index] = elem.getNome() + "" + elem.getCognome();
            index++;
        }
    }
}


}
```

Maybe I'm doing completly wrong, anyway I think that one of my error could be here:

```
bundle.putParcelable("profilo", (Parcelable) profili);
```

I'll gladly accept any advice and explanation

Here's the stacktrace

```
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 2262
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginChooser}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Profilo[]
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Profilo[]
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginChooser.onCreate(LoginChooser.java:21)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-10 18:54:37.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2262):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: but what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("profilo", profili);
```

and read it back this way:

```
ArrayList<Profilo> profili =  getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("profilo");
```

Comment: I have no compiling errors but when I press the button to start the activity the app crashes.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Just added to the original post

Comment: did you changed your code accordingly to my answer?

Comment: It still the same problem, when I press the button the app crashes, I'm doing something wrong for sure, but I have not been able to find out my error since the code seems good